# How to call input tag to the c# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using a bootstrap to show up calender for the user to pick the range of date and call in data from the database. I use it from the following link.
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

It works fine but since this is using input tag. I don't know how to call in the code behind (C#). Please note that i'm using asp.net.

```
                <td style="width:200px">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker6'>
                            <input type='text' class="form-control" id="Tdate1" runat="server" name="Tdate1"/>
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="width:100px">&nbsp;<span style="padding-left:40%; padding-bottom:20%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right"></span>&nbsp;</td>
            <td  style="width:200px">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker7'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" id="Tdate2" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>



   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
             format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
         });
         $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
             format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
             useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075

         });
         $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {

             $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);

         });
         $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
             $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
         });
     });
```

A little bit more information on what i'm trying to achieve.

```
SqlCommand cmddetail = new SqlCommand();
    cmddetail.Connection = con;
    cmddetail.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmddetail.CommandText = " SELECT * FROM ";
    cmddetail.CommandText += " WHERE DATE1 >= '" + //calling Tdate1 + "'  AND DATE2 <= '" //calling Tdate2 ";
```

Usually if we use dropdownlist we would just call it by ddl.selectedvalue. 
And if it is in form of text. we would just "string name123 = textbox1.text" and then call name123 in the sql.

Since this is using input type. How do I call it in the code behind?

Comment: Side note: Any particular reason of showing off SQL injection in your code? That may reflect purely on overall impression left after reading the post.

Comment: @idwell, Your bootstrap datepicker is a client-side control, are you expecting it to work as a server-side control

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry I'm a new Intern at a small company. So I don't really catch what you are trying to say. Care to explain more? I'm willing to learn any new things ! Thank you

Comment: @Anand While I'm not really sure what you are talking about. I can say that I've completed it. Thank you for commenting !

Comment: @idwell, what you are asking for is a server-side wrapper for the client-side date picker control. By server-side, I mean an ASP.NET Control which renders either partially or completely in server-side and client-side means a JavaScript plugin that renders completely in client-side(browser)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually in ASP.NET you use

```
<asp:TextBox Class="form-control" ID="Tdate1" runat="server" ToolTip="Tdate1"/>
```

instead of

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id="Tdate1" runat="server" name="Tdate1"/>
```

and access it by calling the `Text` property `Tdate1.Text`

Comment: While correct, it may not help OP at all: there is a good chance OP is using ASP.Net MVC as there is no `<asp:` whatsoever in the sample...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the question is tagged ASP.NET

Comment: @fubo, your answer is fine if OP wants to access Text property, what if he wants to access some other JavaScript property like 'useCurrent' ? ASP TextBox control does not support this property, in such cases a server side wrapper is the ideal choice. By wrapper, I mean a server-side ASP.NET control that renders JavaScript date picker

Answer (score 2):

You can put attribute `runat="server"` in the `<input>` control this will give you the possibility of finding it in the code behind.

Also when you are putting the values of the input in your query use `SqlCommand` Parameters, to prevent from [Sql Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Here how you can do it.

```
SqlCommand cmddetail = new SqlCommand();
cmddetail.Connection = con;
cmddetail.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmddetail.CommandText = @" SELECT * FROM WHERE DATE1 >= @CallingDate1 AND DATE2 <= @CallingDate2";
cmddetail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallingDate1", input1Cnl.Text);
cmddetail.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallingDate2", input2Cnl.Text);
```

Also using symbol `@` before start the string give you the possibility to write strings on more than one line. You can use it.